# Which spiritual organisation offers free meditation guidance in India?

Tags: yoga, meditation, kriyayoga, raja-yoga

In India there are many spiritual organisations which teach [meditation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meditation) while some charge and some do not charge money wise.

For example:

- **Art of living**: charge money.
- **Vipassana**: Does not charge.
- **Isha foundation**: charge money.
- **Siddhant Yoga Sangh**: charge money

which organisations/gurus do not charge compulsorily for teaching meditation?

Comment: You can do Isha Upa Yoga and Isha Kriya for free.

Comment: I think local centers of such institutions charge some fee because they have to rent a space and pay  for electricity charges etc.  They also give you certificate after completion. So their courses are not entirely free , but they charges some amount but not for profit.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: Its okay in charging money. I am not againt nor I have complained about charging money. My question is about knowing organisation/guru which do not charge.

Comment: OK. But you are confusing  between  main spiritual organisations and the regional/local centers which  conduct their various courses and take exams etc. See these organisations teach meditation in courses consisting of some fixed duration and also have levels like basic, intermediate etc. which requires qualified teachers who has completed their courses and are eligible to teach.

Comment: The course fee gose to the teachers who also are required to earn their bread and butter + operative expenses+course material.Also changing money ensures that the person attending is serious otherwise a free couse will attract all sorts of crowd.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: I have already told you that its okay in charging money. My question is not about knowing if one should charge or not.